# TFS 2013 automated build: Is there a way to run the tests from the src folder

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently using the default build process template in TFS 2013 for my automated builds.

I've configured the `OutputLocation` parameter to be `AsConfigured` to get the same folder structure as my Visual Studio solution (there are multiple projects in the solution and I don't want them all to be dropped in the same folder).

The problem is that when the build process tries to run the tests, it looks for any assembly under the `bin` folder, while my build configuration makes it so that there is only a `src` folder.

Is there a way to specify looking into the `src` folder instead? Shouldn't it be the default anyway when using the `AsConfigured` setting?

**Edit**: Just to make it clear, there are usually 3 folders generated when running a TFS automated build (src, bin, tst). When using AsConfigured for the output location, there is no bin folder. I tried a suggestion which required changing the `Test sources spec` setting of the build process, and I get the same problem as before:

```
There were no matches for the search pattern C:\Builds\8\MyProject\MyBuildDefinition\bin\***test*.dll
```

Comment: I've been having this exact issue, took me hours to figure out that it was switching to `AsConfigured` that stopped running the tests, did you get it working?

Comment: It's a shame that the official MS response is to hard-code in the path. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/be5be6f0-2092-4786-be1b-7b86b22dbcae/tfs-2013-automated-build-is-there-a-way-to-run-the-tests-from-the-src-folder?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: See also http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/30c8b8e8-01d9-47fb-a370-57b5d190006c/using-asconfigured-and-still-be-able-to-get-unittest-results?forum=tfsprocess

Comment: The "..\src" trick mentioned here *may* work (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208054/using-asconfigured-and-still-be-able-to-get-unittest-results-in-tfs/24327943#24327943) but I found I ran into new issues with [DeploymentItem]s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using a PowerShell script as a post-build event to copy my test assemblies to the bin folder of the build.

There are PowerShell scripts made available for TFS 2013 on CodePlex, and I modified [this one](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Scripts/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1) slightly to accomodate my needs.

By doing this, I was able to use the default settings for running the tests, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I was already using a modified version of the PowerShell script, so simply adding my test assemblies did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your build definition, change the value of setting "Test Sources spec" to ***test*.dll (assuming your unit tests assemblies are suffixed with .test.dll)

EDIT: Please use ****\*test*.dll;****\*test*.appx

Comment: Then try out ..\**test*.dll

Comment: I have edited the answer. Didn't realize that SO omitted my blackslashes. Hope this helps

Comment: @HamidShahid this doesn't seem to work for me either. Using the other two options works but AsConfigured doesn't seem to run tests.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. Also, `**\*test*.dll` is the default value (at least for TfvcTemplate.12.xaml workflow)

Comment: This by itself won't work because the bin directory is empty when using the `AsConfigured` build option.  You'll need to implement a script like @Deli suggested.  Then the value of your setting will work as designed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this file masks: `..\**\*test*.dll`

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have "AsConfigured" setting on for X64 platform that places the binaries into `src\x64\Release\` (and it used to place them into `bin\x64\Release\` without that switch). So, I ended up using `..\..\..\src\**\*test*.dll` as my "Test Sources spec".